# Keeping divergent versions of a hg version-controlled file on different machines?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am working on a project that depends on external programs, and needs to know the paths to them. I develop and use the project on several machines, using mercurial for version control. The paths are machine-dependent, so I keep them in a machine-specific config file. I would like the config file for each host to be version-controlled, but I need to ensure that the config file from one host would never overwrite the config file for another host when pushing or pulling between hosts. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm guessing that the name of the file is the same though? Would it be possible to have 1 common file "template" script, and not version-control the specific ones? That way, you would just have to delete the machine-specific file and rerun the script to produce it. This script would then check which machine it is on and produce the right file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, Wim is right: machine specific configurations shouldn't be part of the project's source control. As long as you walk alone, this isn't a real problem, but once you want to provide *generic* releases of your project, you have to get rid of them. In that case you might not be happy about the fact, that the change history contains files with machine specific data.

Nevertheless, it may make sense to have machine specific data in version controlled files (personally I do this for my *dot-rc* files and shell scripts). In that case I would suggest to separate *generic* and *specific* configurations into different files and include/utilize the *specific* one at build- or runtime, depending on the currently used machine.

If it is not possible to detect the current machine automatically, you could still create an unversioned symbolic link on each machine, pointing to the appropriate *specific* configuration file. For instance, on the machine *foo* the file layout could look like this:

- `generic.conf` *version-controlled*
- `specific-foo.conf` *version-controlled*
- `specific-bar.conf` *version-controlled*
- `specific.conf` → `specific-foo.conf` *unversioned symbolic link*

An alternative to symbolic links is to use a [hook](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) which automatically creates `specific.conf`, e.g. on each invocation of `hg update`. As hooks are set in a repository's *hgrc* file, it can be defined individually on each machine. Here's an example of a corresponding *hooks* section in the `.hg/hgrc` file of a repository clone on the machine *foo*:

```
[hooks]
update = cp specific-foo.conf specific.conf
```

Comment: I like the idea of configfile-host1.conf, configfile-host2.conf, etc. I could probably write a hook that creates the symlinks automatically. Or maybe even set up the makefile so that it automatically reads the correct machine-specific config file.

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, the *makefile* way would be the best one, in my opinion. Note that if you use symlinks, you actually don't need hooks, because you set the symlinks once on each machine and that's it. I don't see a reason to also use hooks here. The hooks based approach is meant to be an alternative for symlinks, for file systems which do not support symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Machine specific configuration settings should not be version controlled in the same repository as the project code.

However, it is still a good idea to put an inactive sample configuration file in your code repository. And this sample could show a bunch of typical locations for the external program paths you mentioned as lines that are commented out. That way you make it easier to get your project running on new machines.